# How to add text Fieldin catalog category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, catalog

How to add text field after **image** for the category  in catalog category tried to copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog` folder to local code pool but not find out where to add a field.

Comment: you can create Category attribute to achieve your requirement.

Comment: you can download custom extension created for category attribute: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4PokeydRXWeaDEwTTRETExoMEk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

you can add new custom category attribute in your Magento store via sql_setup script.

MySQL setup script will look something like this, it depends on your needs and how you would like to configure your new attribute:

```
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
    $attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
    $attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'new_cat_attrb',  array(
        'type'     => 'int',
        'label'    => 'New Category Attribute',
        'input'    => 'text',
        'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'           => true,
        'required'          => false,
        'user_defined'      => false,
        'default'           => 0
    ));


    $installer->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId,
        $attributeSetId,
        $attributeGroupId,
        'new_cat_attrb',
        '11'                    //last Magento's attribute position in General tab is 10
    );

    $attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, 'new_cat_attrb');

    $installer->run("
    INSERT INTO `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity_int')}`
    (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, `value`)
        SELECT '{$entityTypeId}', '{$attributeId}', `entity_id`, '1'
            FROM `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity')}`;
    ");


    //this will set data of your custom attribute for root category
    Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->load(1)
        ->setImportedCatId(0)
        ->setInitialSetupFlag(true)
        ->save();

    //this will set data of your custom attribute for default category
    Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->load(2)
        ->setImportedCatId(0)
        ->setInitialSetupFlag(true)
        ->save();

    $installer->endSetup();
```

In your config.xml file of your module you will need to add this part in order to install correctly your new category attribute:

```
    <resources>
        <new_attribute_csv_setup>
          <setup>
            <module>New_Attribute</module>
            <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
          </setup>
          <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
          </connection>
        </new_attribute_setup>
        <new_attribute_setup_write>
          <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
          </connection>
        </new_attribute_setup_write>
        <new_attribute_setup_read>
          <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
          </connection>
        </new_attribute_setup_read>
    </resources>
```

Pay attention on class tag here, class must be: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup`.

Reference [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can see a new tab general tab in category form.

<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("catalog_category", "testfield",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "label"    => "test",
    "input"    => "text",
    "class"    => "",
    "global"   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "user_defined"  => false,
    "default" => "0",
    "searchable" => false,
    "filterable" => false,
    "comparable" => false,

    "visible_on_front"  => false,
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));
$installer->endSetup();
```